# Compare object and add elements that does not match

Tags: javascript

I've object of days where employees is scheduled to work on that day. On website I need to show remaining day as leave. If employee was assigned two different shift, the object can have two elements.

```
var WorkDays = [{day:3}, {day:3}, {day:1}, {day:1}, {day:0}];
var days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}];
```

Newly created WordDays Should be look like this

```
 WorkDays = [{day:0}, {day:1}, {day:1},{day:2}, {day:3}, { day:3} ,{ day:4}, {day:5}, {day:6}];
```

Comment: To clarify: the days that are not initially in WorkDays are leave days, right? Shouldn't they be designated with a key other than `day`?

Comment: Yes Days that are not in WorkDays are leaves. Actaully I will have other array which will show day index as Monday, tue. ..

Comment: The output is an invalid json because has repeated keys.

Comment: Did you mean `[{day:0}, {day:1},...] `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you meant:** `[{day:0}, {day:1},...]`

You can use the function `reduce`.

```js
var WorkDays = [{day:3}, {day:3}, {day:1}, {day:1}, {day:0}],    
    days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = days.reduce((days, c) => {
      if (!days.some(({day}) => day === c)) days.push({day: c});
      return days;
    }, WorkDays).sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day);
    
    console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you explain bit of it. I am not getting anything in it even if it works

Comment: @BreanaJames see the updated answer, I think it's more readable.